# Chain complex of modules and homology with coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand some variations of singular chain complex and their homology.

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space. We have the abelian groups $C_n(X)$ of simplicial $n$-chains and the corresponding chain complex
$$
  \dotsb
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_n
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_{n-1}
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  \dotsb
$$

Every abelian group can be identified with a $\mathbb Z$-module over the integers. So the above chain complex of abelian groups translates into a chain complex of $\mathbb Z$-modules. The homology groups of the chain complex above are abelian groups, too, and as $\mathbb Z$-modules they translate to the homology modules of the $\mathbb Z$-module complex.

> **Q1:** Is this correct so far?

More akin to the textbooks, I can consider the tensor product of the original chain complex with an abelian group $G$, giving the chain complex with coefficients in $G$, 
$$
  \dotsb
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_n \otimes G
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_{n-1} \otimes G
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  \dotsb
$$

> **Q2:** Are the homology groups of this complex isomorphic to the homology groups of the first complex?

Above we have two variations of the original chain complex. Now suppose that I have a ring $R$.

Let $C_n^R$ be the free $R$-module generated by the singular chains of $X$. We then have a chain complex of $R$-modules
$$
  \dotsb
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_n^R
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_{n-1}^R
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  \dotsb
$$

We can also forget the ring structure of $R$ and consider it an abelian group. We then have the chain complex with coefficients in $R$:
$$
  \dotsb
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_n \otimes R
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  C_{n-1} \otimes R
  \xrightarrow{\enspace \partial \enspace}
  \dotsb
$$

> **Q3:** How do the homology groups / modules of these chain complex relate to each other?

Comment: For Q2, see the Universal Coefficient Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem

Comment: For a (commutative, with unit) ring $R$, $C_n^R \simeq C_n\otimes R$

Comment: Let me add to @Max's comment that we equip the $\mathbb Z$-module $C_n\otimes_{\mathbb Z} R$ with the structure of an $R$-module by multiplication into the right factor of simple tensors.